# Does it imply that $f$ also continuous on the closed disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ is analytic on $\{|z|<1\}$ and that $u(z)$ extends to be continuous on the closed disk $\{|z|\leq1\}$. Show that $\displaystyle f(z)=\int_0^{2\pi}u(e^{i\theta})\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}+iv(0)$ for $|z|<1$.

I wanted to use Cauchy formula for $f(z)$, but in order use it we need to have $f$ to be continuous on  the closed disk $\{|z|\leq1\}$. But it is given that only $u$ satisfy that condition. My question is does it imply that $f$ also continuous on the closed disk?

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)$ is not guaranteed to be defined for $|z| = 1$, because you get $e^{it} = z$ in the integrand for some $t$.

This is the Poisson integral of $u$. We show that $u(z)$ is the real part of
$$
f_1(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}u(e^{it})dt
$$
for $z\in D$, and $f_1\in H(D)$, where $D$ is the open unit disk. Then $f$ and $f_1$ can only differ by an additive constant.

The real part of $f_1$ is the Poisson integral $P[u]$ of boundary values of $u$. Let $u_1$ be such that $u_1 = u$ on the boundary and $u_1$ = $P[u]$ in $D$. $u_1$ is continuous on $\bar{D}$ and harmonic in $D$ (read any complex analysis book for these facts about the Poisson integral).

Put $h=u-u_1$, $h$ is harmonic and vanishes on the boundary. Assume that $h(z_0)>0$ for some $z_0\in D$, fix $\epsilon \in (0,h(z_0))$, and define
$$
g(z) = h(z)+\epsilon |z|^2
$$
for $z\in \bar{D}$. $g = \epsilon$ on the boundary, and $g(z_0) > \epsilon$, so $g$ has a local maximum at some $z_1\in D$, where $g_{xx}(z_1)\leq 0$ and $g_{yy}(z_1)\leq 0$. But $\Delta g(z_1) = 4\epsilon$, which is a contradiction. Thus $u-u_1\leq 0$. For the same reason, $u_1-u\leq 0$, so $u=u_1$.

To show that $f_1\in H(D)$, note that for any $z\in D$,
$$
\left|\frac{z}{e^{it}}\right| < 1.
$$
Hence the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{e^{i(n+1)t}} = \frac{1}{e^{it}-z}
$$
converges uniformly for $t\in [0,2\pi]$, and
$$
f_1(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}}{e^{i(n+1)t}}u(e^{it})dt + z \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{u(e^{it})}{e^{i(n+1)t}}dt\right)
$$
is a power series that converges in $D$. Hence $f_1$ is holomorphic in $D$.

Note: The general statement for the last part is as follows: Suppose that $\mu$ is a complex measure on a measurable space $X$, $\varphi$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, $\Omega$ is an open set not intersecting $\varphi(X)$. Then
$$
f(z) = \int_X\frac{d\mu}{\varphi - z}
$$
defines a function $f\in H(\Omega)$. The proof is exactly the same.